# Usage of X-AppEngine-Estimated-CPM-US-Dollars in AppEngine

Tags: java, google-app-engine

How to make use of **X-AppEngine-Estimated-CPM-US-Dollars** header in AppEngine.
i read some docs, we can make use of it with only Administrator credentials, what is this mean?

if you have any samples please do share with us.

Thanks in Advance! :)

Comment: It means that this extra header will be added only for admin-users. Because usually you don't want to show to app users how much you pay for hosting.

Comment: I'm admin user but i didn't see any header like this.
can you please guide me how we can proceed to get this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't do anything special to enable this functionality. I have role `Owner` for my app as displayed on page https://appengine.google.com/ Administration > Permissions.

If I logout from my Google Account - this header dissapear.
Additional headers appear if I logged in into my Google Account and visit secured area on my site.

Secured area marked like this in `web.xml`:

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Administration resources</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/admin/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>admin</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

And it looks like this in Firebug:
[image]

Comment: Super, i configured and it is working well.

Thank you soo much!

Answer (score 0):

The header itself is explained at http://googleappengine.blogspot.com/2009/08/new-features-in-124.html?m=1. It's 1,000 times what you would have paid Google to serve the page, if you had no free quotas. (Of course, actually serving the exact same page 1,000 times is likely to cost less because of caching.)